# Recover filesystem after resize FAT32

Tags: filesystems, gparted, fat32

I recently resized one partition inside an LVM on my disk using `gparted`. No errors were given, but now the filesystem is corrupted and I'm trying to recover it.

When I mount it, no errors appear but when I `ls` into the mount point I have a directory full of files/directories with broken attributes that give input/output error. To be more explicit, all files have a random name except for one detail, a dot always in the same position. For example, these are two of the file names: `?enOxfJl.mul`, `FMgUIKEJ.ahg`.

I suspect there's some "shift" in the filesystem, also because one of the files is named `-----BEG.IN`, that looks exactly like the beginning of a PGP message, and I actually have some of them in that partition.

I already used PhotoRec to recover readable files and it seems that nothing is really lost, I recovered quite everything but that software cannot restore also the directory tree.

I wonder if there are some kind of tricky mount options to read again the filesystem without recreating it, or simply some software to repair that broken fs. I already tried TestDisk, but it seems more appropriate for restoring broken partition tables than filesystems

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the relevant VG config backup.  On this machine I'm on now (Debian 9), VG config backups get written to `/etc/lvm/archive/`.  Helpfully, each backup contains a description of the command that was run, so it shouldn't be too hard to figure out which one it was.
2. Use `vgcfgrestore` to put the old VG config back in place.
3. Assuming you didn't screw up the filesystem with your previous attempts to fix it, it should mount now.
4. Setup a decent backup regime.

If `gparted` doesn't create VG backup files, then chalk whole episode up as a learning experience, both in why backups are rather important, as well as why `gparted` is a steaming pile that should be avoided at all possible costs.

Comment: - I have a backup, I want to restore the partition as a challenge to learn something because I saw that strange name pattern of the files.
- Unfortunately, I don't even have a `/etc/lvm/archive`, so I think `gparted` didn't save any history of the resize.

Comment: You say that `gparted` should be avoided at all costs, but can you tell me the reason?

Comment: Well, the fact that it doesn't keep backups of VG metadata would be enough by itself.